# spring mvc mock test web app context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
public class MyController {    

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testParam")
    public String update() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

My Test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/META-INF/config/applicationContext.xml"})
public class MyControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

       @Test
       public void testUpdate2() throws Exception {
             this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
                    mockMvc.perform(get("/testParam")).andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("test"));
       }


        @Test
        public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
            MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController()).build()
                    .perform(get("/testParam")).andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("test"));
        }
}
```

Question 1):
When I run above tests, testUpdate2 fails saying AssertionError: Status expected <200> but was:<404>

2) If RequestMethod.POST, how can I test it?

eg:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insert")
    public String insertRequests() {
        return "page";
    }
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void insert() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
            mockMvc.perform(post("/insert")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("page"));
}
```

above Test fails: AssertionError: Status expected <200> but was:<404>

**Edit**

My jsps file is under location:  "\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsps\pages\test.jsp"
i am using tiles.xml file configuration.

xml file:

```
 <beans..>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/pages/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Comment: Im not familier with spring, 
but i suggest you to use F12 in Chrome browser.
You can view more infromation with it and maybe solve the problem by yourself!

Comment: Could you add code snippet of your classpath:/META-INF/config/applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 1):

In your view resolver, did you map your prefix value to "/WEB-INF/". If so then
your

> ```
>                 .andExpect(forwardedUrl("test"));
> ```

should be

> ```
>               .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/test.jsp"));
> ```

Comment: I have given .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsps/pages/test.jsp"));, but still gets same error.